# how to find the start value of an Oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

I want to get the start value of an Oracle sequence. I use the command `SELECT * FROM user_sequences`. But there is not the column of start value. Is there an easy way to get the start value?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, generally you cannot do this. Look:

```
SQL> create sequence s start with 100 increment by -10 minvalue 0 maxvalue 1000 cycle;

Sequence created.

SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value, increment_by, last_number 
   2 from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'S';

SEQUENCE_N  MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY LAST_NUMBER                       
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -----------                       
S                   0       1000          -10         100                       

SQL> select s.nextval from dual connect by level <= 5;

   NEXTVAL                                                                      
----------                                                                      
       100                                                                      
        90                                                                      
        80                                                                      
        70                                                                      
        60                                                                      

SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value, increment_by, last_number 
   2 from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'S';

SEQUENCE_N  MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY LAST_NUMBER                       
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -----------                       
S                   0       1000          -10         -10
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of trying to read the start value from the sequence, you can infer it from the numbers that it has generated. Min(), or Max() for a descending sequence, selected from whichever column it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ddl command to find the start with value , the statement used to created the sequence.

```
SQL>   SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE','GEN_VALUES') FROM dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('SEQUENCE','GEN_VALUES')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SCOTT"."GEN_VALUES"  MINVALUE 1000 MAXVALUE 1000000 INCREME
NT BY 1 START WITH 1000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
```

Comment: He cannot. It would just use current value (i.e. LAST_NUMBER) as start one.